# How to give link to a value fetched from database which leads the user to details of the same database table using java webapp developement

Tags: java, web-applications

I have certain entries in my data base. Let the columns be 'name', 'age' , 'email' and 'contact number'. Suppose i have 10 entries into this table. Now from my java code i am bringing all the 10 name into a webpage which is listed as links. Upon clicking the names i need to get their detail
For Eg. If there is a name entry 'anoop', on clicking 'anoop' its should show corresponding age, email, and contact number of that particular row with name as 'anoop'. I can populate the dropdown menu,but i want to know whether this approach will work or not with java !!!!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking. Can you post your java code, and possibly more details on what exactly isn't working?

Comment: To make it much more clear, if we are searching in google, it shows the results as links right. I want to do an operation like that

Answer (score 0):

Hi
 On page loading get all your Names from database and populate it into drop down box .On selecting the name trigger an ajax call and get the information related to that "Name" display it in the same page.

Comment: Yes you said it right. Populating a drop down is possible.